# r - calculate transactions per second

Tags: r

If I have a dataset with a date as such:

```
head(ds$TransStartTmdte) 

[1] "2011-05-09 08:50:12" "2011-05-09 09:03:46" "2011-05-09 09:06:49" "2011-05-09 09:13:05" "2011-05-09 14:21:58" "2011-05-09 14:23:00"
```

Where each row repressents a "transaction" how can I calculate transactions per second.

The date format is POSIXt

```
dput(head(ds$TransStartTmdte))

structure(list(sec = c(0.007, 0.013, 0.018, 0.012, 0.043, 0.039
), min = c(34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L), hour = c(14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L), mday = c(9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L), mon = c(4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), year = c(111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L
), wday = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), yday = c(128L, 128L, 128L, 
128L, 128L, 128L), isdst = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("sec", 
"min", "hour", "mday", "mon", "year", "wday", "yday", "isdst"
), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt"))
```

Comment: Your question is a little ambiguous.  Can you please clarify what you mean?  Average number of transaction per second?  Number of transactions for each unique second?  For each entry the number of transaction during last 1000 micro-seconds?

Comment: I am looking for a definition of "transactiosns per second" at tpc.org I want to plot a "running average" of transactions per second.

Comment: Funny, but the dput you give, does not coincide with the head(ds$TransStartTmdte) you show in your post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this works for you?

```
table(cut(transactionTime, "secs"))
```

Example:

```
plot(table(cut(ds$TransStartTmdte, "secs")), main=mydataset ,xlab="date ", ylab="Trans",pch=20)
```

[image]